# Why should I use encapsulation vs abstraction?

Tags: java, python, oop

I have always gone with the popular convention of using access modifiers and encapsulation in order to make sure a class wouldn't break if it was implemented wrong. However, I have noticed that OOP really doesn't need encapsulation and that using access modifiers actually induces more headaches than benefits. Additionally, by not using access modifiers you are being more of an OO programmer. My reasoning is listed below.

1. Python supports OOP yet it does not use access modifiers or encapsulation. Showing that in OOP languages access modifiers are not mandatory.
2. Although compilers are more advanced are still nano-second differences between using accessor method versus variable access. In restricted systems like `Android` this would affect a games FPS drastically. (Although using the final modifier on methods would reduce the nano-second difference significantly in most cases)
3. By not using private or package modifiers coding gets simpler and faster for the original coder. Future user of the class would still be able to use public interfaces without breaking or playing with the class implementations. Furthermore, if he wishes to modify or upgrade the class he may still do so and access the private modifiers. In an analogy, when you decide to modify a car you know there is a possibility that you may break something, but if you're willing to take the risks and know what you're doing being allowed to open a lock that has a clear sign saying (open at your own risks) is better than having to replace the unbreakable lock, locking the part you wish to modify.

What I do now is a mix of public modifiers for public interfaces and protected modifiers for implementation details so users can do their risk-taking by sub-classing. Is there any reason why I should reconsider doing this instead of conventional encapsulation?

Comment: it's nice to say "users may take the risk", unless the user is another programmer in your very large project, which crashes in production because you changed the behavior of a base class.

Comment: I like python -- I don't like java (what little of it I've seen).  I'd do it python's way.  Of course, that's just one bias programmer's opinion :)

Comment: You should use encapsulation and abstraction where appropriate.  Where appropriate is subjective.

Comment: IMO, this question should be asked on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DonRoby - +100.  or more simply: use your brain when choosing how you write programs

Comment: Nice question but the question doesn't sound like it fits Stackoverflow.com. You are true that using getter and setter is nano-second slower than just abstracting values through public attributes. I believe this is something that Java is going to have to improve in future.

Comment: @TemporaryNickName - Actually, the JIT compilers in HotSpot JVMs have inlined simple getters and setters for *many years*.  There should be ZERO performance difference unless the optimization is inhibited by overriding in the getters and setters, etcetera.  Perhaps you are thinking of (early) Android releases.